# Parse .pbxproj files on linux

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, plist

Ive been looking for some way to convert .pbxproj files to xml files for parsing for a CI pipeline. On mac, I can use "plutil -convert xml1 < filename >", and it works perfectly, but Linux's open source plist parsing tool is [full of bugs](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist/issues/83) and fails (even with debug mode) with a basic "failed to convert plist file".

Is there any alternative solution/way of parsing this file? Our goal is to validate that all files are included in multiple xcode targets.

Comment: I don't know about parsing but you can generate Xcodeproj with XcodeGen. In XcodeGen's YML config you can give source directories for each target.

Comment: Would that require us to constantly regenerate xcodeproj files?

Comment: No, it is not required. I check-in pbxproj file so I don't have dependency on XcodeGen. When you regenerate just keep in mind config has updated to changes you have made directly in Xcode. You don't have to update config for new files inside existing source directories.

Comment: The solution I'm looking for would prevent a bad pbxproj from being uploaded in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with ruby, you can use [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) gem. It allows you to parse the `pbxproj` file directly, without conversion into `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already figured out, the pbxproj is actually just a plist (in old-style, nextstep format I believe; http://www.monobjc.net/xcode-project-file-format.html).

In order to parse it, you need to be able to [parse a plist on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681949/plutil-equivalent-in-ubuntu/1325138#1325138).

There are a few options there, including [plist-util](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libplist-utils/plistutil.1.en.html), which works but does not have the same API. Personally, I forked a [drop-in replacement for plutil](https://github.com/screenplaydev/plutil) so that I didn't need to update our scripts to account for Linux and Mac envs separately.